# SonargraphMeasureComputer error in SonarQube background task log

Tags: sonarqube

We are using SonarQube 5.4 and we found the following log lines:

```
....
INFO  [c.q.p.s.s.p.e.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer] Computed measure 'SMELL_COUNT_BAD_FRAMEWORK_USAGE': 0)
INFO  [c.q.p.s.s.p.e.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer] Computed measure 'SMELL_COUNT_USELESS_TEST': 0)
INFO  [c.q.p.s.s.p.e.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer] Computed measure 'SMELL_COUNT_WRONG_LANGUAGE': 0)
INFO  [c.q.p.s.s.p.e.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer] Computed measure 'SMELL_COUNT_WRONG_LOGIC': 0)
ERROR [c.h.s.m.SonargraphMeasureComputer] Not processing for module: xxx
ERROR [c.h.s.m.SonargraphMeasureComputer] Not processing for module: xxx
INFO  [c.q.p.s.s.p.e.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer] Computing measures for component 'xxx' and level PROJECT)
INFO  [c.q.p.s.s.p.e.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer] Computed measure 'SMELL_COUNT': 0)
ERROR [c.h.s.m.SonargraphMeasureComputer] Not processing for module: xxx
ERROR [c.h.s.m.SonargraphMeasureComputer] Not processing for module: xxx
INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   Execution time for each component visitor:
INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - LoadComponentUuidsHavingOpenIssuesVisitor | time=79ms
INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - IntegrateIssuesVisitor | time=29920ms
...
```

We could not find an explanation for the error lines. Does anyone have any ideas?